# selenium send key for xpath not working

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, sendkeys

I want make automation for this [web site](https://www.easybooking.lk/) 
in this web site 3 text box are here check image

1st text box x path is `/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/searchbar[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]`

here is my code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/searchbar[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("rio salon");
```

when I run this code I got this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

How can i fix it? I hope my `xpath` is correct.

[image]

Comment: Check with this xpath for the 1st textbox ::
//*[@id="search-form"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/span[1]

Comment: at login.eb.main(eb.java:24)`

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id=\"search-form\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/span[1]")).sendKeys("rio salon");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field has `aria-hidden=true` attribute, so you get `ElementNotInteractableException`. You need to click on the dropdown first to change the attribute to `true`

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-form']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"));
dropdown.click();
WebElement textField = dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("./parent::div/following-sibling::input[contains(@class, 'ui-select-search')]"));
textField.sendKeys("rio salon");
```

Comment: @sanjan What do you mean?

Comment: xpath is different how to get those xpath?

Comment: @sanjan [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864639/5168011) has good explanation how to get `xpath` for element, the dropdown in this case . From there I tested in the console how to get to the text field with `parent` and `sibling`.

Comment: @sanjan Note that I'm using the located dropdown to locate the text field, not the driver.

Comment: i understand now but i have a question my xpath is correct why my code is not working?

Comment: @sanjan I explained it in the answer, the text field is not visible before the click, so you can't send text to it.

Comment: but i try 
1.click
2.send key also its also wont work

Comment: @sanjan The click and send text are in two different elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can click in an input field with a `div` or `span` tag, but you cannot type in the field. So, your XPath must be written with an `input` tag if you want to `sendkeys` or type in an input field. For example:

```
//input[contains(@placeholder,'Site')]
```