# How to get the last table in xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

So I have the following situation:

```
<table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
</table>
<table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
</table>
```

as you can see I have two table with the same classes, I want get the last table (I cannot use index because the number of the table changing).

For the moment I have this code:

```
HtmlNode oddsTable = doc.DocumentNode
         .SelectNodes("//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable']");
```

unfortunately I cannot find any `.Last()` method, maybe is possible do this directly with `xpath` so without use `SelectNodes()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath for elements using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864280/xpath-for-elements-using-chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT getting last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459132/xslt-getting-last-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `last()` as index

```
"(//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable'])[last()]"
```

Be sure to wrap the expression in parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

`last()` will return you the last table only if both tables are children of the same parent. So if HTML really looks like

```
<table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
</table>
<table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
</table>
```

then

```
//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable'][last()]
```

will fetch required table...

But in case

```
<div>
    <table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table-main detail-odds sortable">
  ..
    </table>
</div>
```

you might need

```
(//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable'])[count(//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable'])]
```

Comment: Thanks also for you answer :)